# Python Flask UnsupportedOperation: not writable

Tags: python, flask

When I run the following code, I get the error message: "UnsupportedOperation: not writable":

```
from flask import Flask

app_flask = Flask(__name__)

@app_flask.route('/')
def hello_method():
    return "Hello, main page!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app_flask.run()
```

Can anyone offer some guidance? I know there's another question like this one, but the answers were not helpful at all. Here's the rest of the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-13-a122d150300b>", line 20, in <module>
    app_flask.run()

  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 938, in run
    cli.show_server_banner(self.env, self.debug, self.name, False)

  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 629, in show_server_banner
    click.echo(message)

  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\utils.py", line 259, in echo
    file.write(message)

UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer here, courtesy of josechval:
https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/257

Jose says:
"You need to edit the "echo" function definition at ../site-packages/click/**utils.py** . The default value for the "file" parameter must be **sys.stdout** instead of **None**.
Do the same for the "secho" function definition at ../site-packages/click/**termui.py**"

Answer (score 4):

Another solution from the same [issue](https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/257) already quoted:

Downgrade flask:

> conda install flask=0.12.2

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 starting the app on port
try: 
    # works fine while running the py script in the command-line 
    app.run(debug=True,port=8000)
except:
    # internal issue with Jupyter Notebook
    print("Exception occured!")
    # running manually
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
    run_simple('localhost', 9000, app)
```

There seems to be an internal issue with jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I  edited the echo function definition at ../site-packages/click/utils.py the default value for the file parameter must be sys.stdout instead of None (line number is 166.
this is --> def echo(message=None, file=sys.stdout, nl=True, err=False, color=None):
I did  the same for the secho function definition at ../site-packages/click/termui.py
line number is 408
this is ---> def secho(text, file=sys.stdout, nl=True, err=False, color=None, **styles):